# Definition of a Running Totals in Programming

Tags: terminology

I teach introductory programming and am having a discussion with one of my colleagues about "Running Totals".  They say that a running total is, by convention (and backed by the Wikipedia article on the topic, only a summation (+).  My argument is that a running total could either a running sum (+) or a running product (*) and that if you just use the term "Running Total", it could potentially mean either and should require clarification.  Is there professional consensus?

Answer (score 1):

Good question, but I have never thought of a Running Total as a product of any kind.

Seems like the word "total" implies addition (or in the context of Accounting, subtraction as well).